# Ruby on Rails auto_complete plugin with pretty urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, autocomplete

I am using the Rails auto_complete plugin: https://github.com/rails/auto_complete

problem is when i submit a GET form containing this line

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :post, title %>
```

the value of the text field gets wrapped in a :post in the url

```
http://myapp.com/posts?post%5Btitle%5D=help
```

I would much prefer

```
http://myapp.com/post?title=help
```

How can i achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried that plugin, but I think
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :post, title, {:name=>'title'} %> should work

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, with your suggestion the urls look fine, but the text_field no longer auto-completes .

Comment: The 3rd param is an optional hash which is passed to find() to find the results. I would think that wont solve anything.